# Poco Library, send get request without body

Tags: c++, http, poco, poco-libraries

I'm learning c++ and I want to create an http request to get just the server time without authentication, nothing more. The problem is I can't get to receive a succesfull response and also I don't know how to see it after I receive it. The url is : **"https://api.binance.com/api/v3/time"** which gives a json response with just the server time.
the code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/URI.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPRequest.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPMessage.h>

int main()
{
//url 
    Poco::URI uri("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/time");
// client session
    Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());
// request
    Poco::Net::HTTPRequest request(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, "/api/v3/time", 
    Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
    
    session.sendRequest(request);
    Poco::Net::HTTPResponse response;
    std::istream& inStream = session.receiveResponse(response);
    cout << response.getStatus() << endl;
   

    return 0;
   
}
```

Comment: Is your question actually "how do I read data from an std::istream"?

Comment: I really don't know If i'm able to do that since I'm still trying to get a correct response, therefore I hadn't the chace to try it. Also when I get the response.getStatus() i always have 400....

Answer (score 0):

You need to do HTTPS request because you are accessing a secure URI:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/URI.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPRequest.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPMessage.h>
#include <Poco/JSON/Parser.h>

int main() {
    const Poco::URI uri("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/time");
    const Poco::Net::Context::Ptr context = new Poco::Net::Context(
            Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "",
            Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_NONE, 9, false,
            "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
    Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(),
            context);
    Poco::Net::HTTPRequest request(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET,
            uri.getPath(), Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
    Poco::Net::HTTPResponse response;
    session.sendRequest(request);
    std::istream &stream = session.receiveResponse(response);
    std::cout << response.getStatus() << " " << response.getReason() << std::endl;
    if (response.getStatus() != Poco::Net::HTTPResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
        // {"serverTime":1654845573698}
        Poco::JSON::Parser parser;
        Poco::Dynamic::Var result = parser.parse(stream);
        Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr object = result.extract<Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr>();
        std::cout << "server time " << object->get("serverTime").toString() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```